# paypal MPL library window doesn't open in device but works on simulator

Tags: ios, paypal

paypal MPL library (ios) works perfectly fine in simulator but on device it's almost a 50% success rate of showing the login window,

below is the array I send to PayPalInst,

```
PayPalAdvancedPayment *payment = [[[PayPalAdvancedPayment alloc] init] autorelease];
[payment setReceiverPaymentDetails:arrInvoice];
[payment setPaymentCurrency:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"USD"]];
[[PayPal getPayPalInst] advancedCheckoutWithPayment:payment];
```

arrInvoice is:

> PayPalAdvancedPayment{   Currency: USD   Receiver(0):
>   PayPalReceiverPaymentDetails {   Recipient:
>   moumit_13371763##_###@#####.com   SubTotal: 430.68   Is Primary: Yes
>   Payment Type: 0   Payment Subtype: -1   Invoice Data: (null)
>   Description: China Med   Custom Id: (null)   Merchant Name: LUCKYLiNK}
>   Receiver(1): PayPalReceiverPaymentDetails {   Recipient:
>   pradip_13338047##_###@#####.com   SubTotal: 12.92   Is Primary: No
>   Payment Type: 0   Payment Subtype: -1   Invoice Data: (null)
>   Description: China Med   Custom Id: (null)   Merchant Name: ###}}

Comment: I am facing same problem. Did you get any solution for this problem???Thanks in advance

Comment: what I found is the paypal library takes some time to initialize regardless of the net speed, so calling the login window when it hasn't initialized resulted in the above behaviour, try using the sdk's paypal buttons for better result.